# Sync active panel with active modal with switch button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row of panels with an active button in each one. In each panel there are a option to edit the panel too, so when it's click to the orange icon (see fiddle below), it's open a modal and shows a list of options, including another button to active the panel that you have clicked from the modal. I want to sync the active button of the modal to the panel that you have clicked, so if i clicked in the panel 3 and in the modal y activated it and click on save changes, the panel 3 will be activated.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FG228/2/

HTML structure of one of the panels:

```
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <div id="2" class="panel panel-off2">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">

      <div class="ptitle">Task 2</div>
       <div class="optiongroup">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow" data-rel="2"></span>
<div class="miniswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" data-id="12">
    <label><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></label>
</div> 
  </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">  
        <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong><span>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <strong>URI:</strong><span>&nbsp;/cron/test</span>/task2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS structure of the switch icons of each panel (miniswitch icons):

```
 $(".miniswitch").click(function () {
    var $panel = $(this).closest('.panel');
    $panel.toggleClass('panel-off2 panel-success');
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', $panel.hasClass('panel-success'))

});
```

JS structure of the switch icons of the modal  (miniswitchmodal icons):

```
 $('.miniswitchmodal input[type=checkbox]').click( function(){
                $( "#chkActive" ).toggleClass("green");
            $( ".ui-widget-header" ).toggleClass("greenhead");
            $( ".ui-widget-header .ui-state-default" ).toggleClass("greenhead noborder");
            $( ".ui-widget-content" ).toggleClass("bordergreen");
         $("input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked',miniswitch);
      });
    $(".miniswitch").click(function () {
    var $panel = $(this).closest('.panel');
    $panel.toggleClass('panel-off2 panel-success');
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', $panel.hasClass('panel-success'))

});
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I want to sync the panels with the modal, so if the panel 3 is active and you click on the yellow icon in the panel to show the modal, the modal has the switch active too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is for the modal events to know what the current panel is. So we can use a global variable (though this is not recommended). Here's a jsfiddle of this: http://jsfiddle.net/FG228/5/

I added a global variable

```
var currentPanel=null  //global variable to store current panel
$(window).resize(function(){
```

Assign the variable when the edit button is clicked

```
$(".glyphicon-edit").click(function () {
    currentPanel=$(this).closest('.panel') //this refers to edit button
```

And finally use it when needed

```
//in  $('.miniswitchmodal input[type=checkbox]').click()
$(currentPanel)
   .toggleClass('panel-off2 panel-success',$("#modalSwitch").attr("checked"))
```

I also added the id `modalSwitch` to the checkbox in the modal dialog for easier reference.

This should get you started, though I recommend looking into other ways of doing it, such as using javascript's ability to have functions inside functions

```
$('.glyphicon-edit').click(function(){
    var currentPanel=this
    $("#btnSave").unbind('click'); //clear the click from other panels
    $("#btnSave").click(function(){
       $(currentPanel).toggleClass(  ...  )
    })

    ...
    ...
})
```

Comment: But the jsfiddle doesn't work right? When i click in the switch button in the modal the panel doesn't activate...

Comment: For me, if I click the switch in the modal, and I click `btnSave` (though I have to change something first. like order maybe to enable `btnSave`), the currentPanel lights up. I only tested in chrome though.

Comment: When i click write anything in an input the modal and i click on save changes, the panel change to active, and i didn't touch the active switch!! I only want to light up the panel when the user switch the switch button in the modal to active, and lights off when the user switch off the switch button in the modal.

Comment: In that case you just "use when needed" where you want it. Since the variable is global it should be usable anywhere as long as currentPanel is set. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: Perfect now, but the panel lights on before i click in save changes, how i can lights on only when i click in save changes, not before?

Comment: I guess you can put the code that activates it in `btnSave` perhaps. You can also do things like get the id, from the panel with `$(currentPanel).attr('id')` for example.

Comment: And how to sync the active button of the modal with the panel? so if the panel 2 has the active input true, in the modal it shows true too.